# how to use Invoke method in a file of extensions/methods?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invoke, invokerequired

Well, I'm writing a file of extensions/method useful to strings,label,linklabels,class etc.

but, I have a problem. I have an `showMessage()` method that change the Text of label, works fine. But I decide to do that works with thread execution, then I do this:

```
namespace LabelExtensions
{
    public static class LabelExtensionsClass
    {        
        private delegate void UpdateState();

        public static void ShowMessage(this Label label, string text)
        {
            if (label.InvokeRequired)
            {
                label.Invoke((UpdateState)delegate
                {
                    label.Text = text;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                  label.Text = text;
            }
        }
}
}
```

**sorry**, it was a typo. I typed this code on forum.
the error continue.

according the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx),to use the Invoke method need to imports:

**Namespace:**  System.Windows.Forms

**Assembly:**  System.Windows.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

then I did:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

but this returns same error:

```
The name 'Invoke' does not exist in the current context
```

how I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the existing `Action` delegate; you don't need to create your own.

Comment: Maybe, `(label.TopLevelControl as Form).Invoke`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
label.BeginInvoke( (Action) (() => label.Text = text));
```

There is no need to create your own delegate. Just use the built-in [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate. You should probably create your extension method for the base [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) class instead of the Label class. It'll be more reusable.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
Invoke((UpdateState)delegate …
```

to

```
label.Invoke((UpdateState)delegate …
```

Comment: Exactly. The "Invoke" method you need is a member of the System.Windows.Forms.Control class, from which Label is derived. Your static LabelExtensions class doesn't have an "Invoke" method.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the label in your code (when you call the Invoke method):

```
public static void ShowMessage(this Label label, string text)
        {
            if (label.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lablel.Invoke((UpdateState)delegate
                {
                    label.Text = text;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                  label.Text = text;
            }
        }
```

also, consider using [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.begininvoke.aspx) instead so you won't block the calling thread (if applicable)

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` is an *instance method* of `Control`.
You need a `Control` to call it on, such as your `label`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare a new delegate type, or construct a new lambda or anonymous delegate. You already have a method that acts on the UI thread - the one you are writing. Just make it call itself on the UI thread if needed, like this.

```
public static void ShowMessage(this Label label, string text) {

    if(label.InvokeRequired) {
        label.Invoke(new Action<Label, string>(ShowMessage), label, text);
        return;
    }

    label.Text = text;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can almost copy and paste the redirection code block from this method to any other method that you want to modify in the same way.